# A unit that is not coherent?

Tags: measurements, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units, metrology

> "Derived units are defined as products of powers of the base units. When the product of powers includes no numerical factor other than one, the derived units are called coherent derived units"

I know that units for quantity such as area (meter squared), volume (meter cubed), velocity (distance per time),..... are coherent. But is there, by any chance, existing a unit that is not coherent ?

Comment: Yes, there are, but not within the SI.

Comment: Consider if you want to express area in acres (or hectares for that matter), volume in quarts, or velocity in miles per hour.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, how about the liter? Not equal to 1  ${\rm m^3}$.

Comment: @ThePhoton The liter is not an SI unit, even though it's tolerated in the SI.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano. Thank you, Mr Massimo. But What I still don't understand is firstly 1 liter (than in this case the numerical factor is 1). Due to this should it not be a coherent unit ?

Comment: I think I misunderstand somewhere. According to what I know and from what I read, coherent unit is basically unit whose numerical factor is one (like m, cm, m/s,...).

Comment: @ProtonUpUpDown $1\,\mathrm{L} = 10^{-3}\,\mathrm{m}^3$, so the numerical factor is not one.

Comment: Oh I get it now. So the coherent derived units are based on the 7 base units. I mean for example the quantity for speed is m/s. This is the coherent units as both the meter and the second are among the base units. If we turn m/s into km/s it would become non-coherent (1 m/s = 0.001 km/s). Is that correct ?

Comment: @ProtonUpUpDown Yes, correct.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Oh my thank you so much. I've been thinking about since yesterday but cannot figure out what it meant. You have saved my day

Answer (score 1):

To condense the answers that have been provided in the comments:

- A *base unit* in the SI is one of the seven established base units (kg, m, s, A, K, cd and mol).
- A *coherent derived unit* is a product of powers of those base units with no added frills: m/s, N, C, J/mol, F, H, and so on.
- Derived units can also have non-unity factors in front of them: kJ/mol, cm/s, pF, g/m$^3$, and so on. These are derived units that are *not* part of the coherent set.